# swift 3 check if timer running

Tags: ios, swift3, timer

I am writing timer functions to check if it is currently running, But It seems that I always found the timer variable to be nil. So that it keeps on creating a new timer instance.

```
weak var myTimer: Timer?

// starting a timer
func startTimer(timer: Timer?, interval: Double, _selector: Selector, _repeats: Bool){
    weak var _timer = timer

    if (_timer == nil){
        _timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: _selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: _repeats)
    }
}

// stopping a timer
func stopTimer(timer: Timer?){
    var _timer = timer

    if (_timer != nil){
        _timer!.invalidate()
        _timer = nil
    }
}
```

Starting the timer by calling

```
self.startTimer(timer: self.myTimer, interval: 0.1, _selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), _repeats: true)
```

Somehow, even after the timer is started, it is still nil. So the second time the function is called, it will schedule another timer instance. And when I try to stop it, it won't be successful, as it was always nil. How can I solve this?

thanks

Comment: Both `_timer` variables are in local scope and not related to each other. What do you expect?

Comment: check the scope and why do you use weak

Comment: I've tried to use non weak var. I tried to use .isValid method but, since it is nil, this won't work.

Comment: Hi Vadian, Timer.ScheduleTimer(... won't allow me to use timer as it is a 'let' constant, that is why I assign a var. Should I return a Timer object in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. You are assigning the new Timer instance to `weak var` inside your function, which will cause it to be deallocated when you exit function scope. The function's `timer` variable must be declared as `inout`

```
func startTimer(timer: inout Timer?, interval: Double, _selector: Selector, _repeats: Bool) {
if (timer == nil){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: _selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: _repeats)
    }
```

The same goes for your second function - you are assigning `nil` only to local variable inside function scope, not to the variable outside.

Comment: Thanks, the 'inout' keyword is the key here. Thank you.